# What postgres type to store a set of strings?

Tags: postgresql

In postgres, what data type should I use to store a unique set of strings?

Is using a simple array then when I want to write, I read the current set of strings, determine what the final set should be considering uniqueness then write it back the best way? Seems somewhat inefficient.

I likely will be commonly do `= ANY` queries too to determine if the array contain an element

A possible data model looks like:

```
BlogPost
- title
- tags: string[]
```

2 common operations:

- Find blog posts with a given tag
- Update the list of tags (while ideally keeping it a unique set)

Comment: Can you provide more information about the data model? Is it a single set of strings in the database? Or a set per row? What do you mean by "set of array"? Have you considered the relational way, i.e. a separate table for the strings?

Comment: @Codo updated post. I want a set per row. Thats a typo

Comment: Stick to the 3NF normalization and use an additional table for this. Don’t use/abuse an array for this

Comment: Do you need the `=ANY(...)` spelling, or just the functionality?

Comment: Similar: [*Arrays in database tables and normalization*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2897615/642706)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use a separate table for the tags. The advantage is that the tags can be indexed and efficiently accessed. The index further guarantees that the tags are unique per post.

```sql
create table blog_post (
  id int8 primary key,
  title varchar(255)
);

create table blog_tag (
  tag varchar(255),
  blog_post_id int8,
  constraint fk_blog_post foreign key(blog_post_id) references blog_post(id)
);

create unique index blog_tag_uk on blog_tag(tag, blog_post_id);

insert into blog_post values(1, 'title1');
insert into blog_tag values('tag-a', 1);
insert into blog_tag values('tag-b', 1);

insert into blog_post values(2, 'title2');
insert into blog_tag values('tag-a', 2);
insert into blog_tag values('tag-c', 2);

select *
from blog_post p left join blog_tag t on t.blog_post_id = p.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question that you want to assure you have unique set of strings for each post, and if so then you can use `TEXT` with UNIQUE to assure that like so:

```
CREATE TABLE BlogPost (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  title TEXT,
  tags TEXT[] UNIQUE
);
```

`UNIQUE` will assure every set you have in the table is unique. If you tried to insert the same set twice you will get an error like so:

```
postgres=# INSERT INTO BlogPost (tags) VALUES ('{"sql", "postgresql"}');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# INSERT INTO BlogPost (tags) VALUES ('{"sql", "postgresql"}');
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "blogpost_tags_key"
DETAIL:  Key (tags)=({sql,postgresql}) already exists.
```

I hope this answers your question, and let me know how it goes with you!

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP meant that the set should not contain duplicate strings, not that the table should not contain two rows with equivalent sets

Comment: Btw, your `UNIQUE` constraint will not prevent the insertion of the array `'{postgresql, sql}'`

Answer (score 0):

@ahmed_131313 is on the correct path but their solution does not correctly create "unique" arrays. It does prohibit multiple occurrences of the *exact same* array. However, is does not uniquely constrain the elements of an array; it allows both `{"postgresql", "sql"}` and `{"sql", "postgresql"}`. The arrays are the same as each element in either exists in the other and there is no element in one that is not in the other.

Rather than a unique constraint you can create a unique index using a function that returns ordered unique values for a given array. So

```
create or replace function order_text_array(source_array_in text[])
  returns text[]
 language sql
 immutable 
 strict  
 parallel safe
/* 
 * order_text_array
 *   input text[]
 *  output text[]
 * 
 * Function returns ordered unique element values from a given array.
 * The functions discards duplicate value from the source as when viewed
 * as a SET the arrays '{"a", "x"}' and '{"a", "a", "x"}' are considered
 * the same set.
 * 
 * RULE: The sets A and B are the same if and only if
 *   For each element in either there exists the same element in the other 
 *   and there is no element in either set that is not in the other. 
 * 
 * Thus {A,B,C} and {A,B,B,C} are the same
 * and  {A,B,C} and {B,A,C} are also the same 
 */
as $$
    select array_agg(e) 
      from (select distinct(e) 
              from unnest(source_array_in) e
             order by 1
           ) sq  
$$;
```

then define the table without unique constraint but create a unique index using the above function.

```
create table blog_post (
                         id    integer generated always as identity 
                                       primary key
                       , title text
                       , tags text[] 
                       );
create unique index unique_single_blog_tag_list 
           on blog_post (order_text_array(tags));
```

See [domo](https://dbfiddle.uk/iETbKpIB) showing each scenario.